# React cleaner way to lift state up

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I've read like 5 SO questions and https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html and I haven't found a better way to do this. I need to toggle a pop-up window from somewhere else in my React project, and their lowest ancestor is App. I need to go through like 20 components across many different files if I want to lift the state up the traditional way (to App, and all the way down to both components). The affected hierarchy looks something like this:

```
App --> RightColumn --> Search --> ... --> SearchCardEntry --> SearchCardEntryColumn
    --> PopupWrapper --> PopupBook
```

I think there has to be a better way, especially with bigger projects with thousands of Components.

Comment: You can also use react-redux to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to easily share data components wide and avoid moving state among way too many layers.

Comment: Thanks for this but I think I will use Naveen's suggestion (redux). Context seems to be better for stuff likes themes

Comment: Not necessarily, it can be used to store various preferences, user authentication status and so on..